# How to set local notification every X minutes?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I am trying to set them like this:

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
              id: 0,
              text: 'Message',
              sound: this.platform.is('android') ? 'file://sound.mp3' : 'file://beep.caf',
              every: this.NotificationsTimer,
              icon: 'notification_icon',
              led: '#ff00c3'
            });
```

`this.NotificationsTimer` has a value of `5`. But it doesn't work, how should I make this work?

Comment: The value of  the property 'every' should be a string, are you using int for this.NotificationsTimer ?

Comment: it has `any` and then a number 5 is assigned, so I have to, `toString()`?

Comment: but when I write just `'5'` instead of `NotificationsTimer` it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the version you get with Ionic right now is 0.8.5. Then you should use `every` with one of the following strings:

- second
- minute
- hour
- day
- week
- month
- quarter

If you are using the latest version (0.9.x, currently in beta), there are more options. The following info is taken from the [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#triggers) repo:

Repeat, relative from now:

```
trigger: { every: 'day', count: 5 }
```

Or every time the date matches:

```
trigger: { every: { month: 10, day: 27, hour: 9, minute: 0 } }
```

Comment: May I know what is count here?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Reading the code it seems like it's not supported on all platforms, but even on the supported platforms I'm not sure it's behaving in a useful way. Sorry, try reading the code and figure it out, otherwise maybe post an issue in the library's GitHub repo?

Comment: But to summarize the behavior of `count`: It will make a recurring notification based on the other trigger criteria. Count is how many times it should appear.

Comment: Actually this is not working in Ionic 3... is there any other alternative?